# how to read jquery.ajax() data in mvc 2 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using mvc2 and jqueries to post the data from view to controller.

This is my view

```
        $('#btnSaveAcademicInfo').click(function() {
        var recordsToSave = [];
        var curRecord = null;
        $.each($("#academics tr"), function(i, v) {
            curRecord = {};
            curRecord.Institution = $(this).find('.tdName').text();
            curRecord.PassoutYear = $(this).find('.tdPassOutYear').text();
            curRecord.Percentage = $(this).find('.tdPercentage').text();
            curRecord.Specialization = $(this).find('.tdspecialization').text();
            recordsToSave.push(curRecord);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/EmployeeMaster/SaveAcademicInfo',
            data: recordsToSave,
            success: function(result) { success(result); },
            datatype: "json"
        });
    });
```

and my controller is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAcademicInfo(List<AcademicModel> data)
    {
        //Here data is always null
        return View("GetPersonalDataById");
    }
```

Here im not getting the data to controller. But when i use, data: JSON.stringify(recordsToSave), I'm able to see the data in firebug.

[image]

How do i read the data in controller.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` converts a javascript object into a JSON string. If you want to send JSON requests in ASP.NET MVC 2 you need a JSON value provider as this is not built-in. See [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) for more details. In ASP.NET MVC 3 this works out of the box thanks to the built-in `JsonValueProviderFactory`.

Also if you want to send a JSON request you need to specify the content type as well:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/EmployeeMaster/SaveAcademicInfo',
    data: JSON.stringify(recordsToSave),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json', // <!-- notice the capital T
    success: function(result) { 
        success(result); 
    },
});
```

and if you don't want to use JSON you will need to format the request in a way that the default model binder can understand. Try like this:

```
var recordsToSave = [];

$.each($('#academics tr'), function (index, value) {
    recordsToSave.push({
        'name': '[' + index + '].Institution',
        'value': $(this).find('.tdName').text()
    });
    recordsToSave.push({
        'name': '[' + index + '].PassoutYear',
        'value': $(this).find('.tdPassOutYear').text()
    });
    recordsToSave.push({
        'name': '[' + index + '].Percentage',
        'value': $(this).find('.tdPercentage').text()
    });
    recordsToSave.push({
        'name': '[' + index + '].Specialization',
        'value': $(this).find('.tdspecialization').text()
    });
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/EmployeeMaster/SaveAcademicInfo',
    data: recordsToSave,
    success: function (result) {
        success(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, its now working. I'm not able to add JsonValueProviderFactory to Global.asax. I'm using mvc2. All I want to do, is to read the data from source as a List<myclass>.

Comment: @Harsha, you could use the JsonValueProviderFactory class described by Phil Haack, download it and include it in your application.

Comment: when I used Microsoft.Web.Mvc dll mentioned by Phil Haack, its working, I'm getting the data in controller. But can't we make it work without the dll?

Comment: @Harsha, did you try the alternative technique I showed in my updated answer?

Comment: if I do it this way, then what should be my controller method paramater datatype, object or List<object> or IEnumerable ?

Comment: @Harsha, your controller action could stay unchanged: `List<AcademicModel>`